# AsyncStorage not fetching data first time

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

in my app i am storing a string in AsyncStrorage and it is storing but to retrive i have to go back one screen and come forward to the desired screen than it will fetch. below is mu code where i am fetching it.

```
let OccupancyType='';
export default class MonthlyAnalysis extends React.Component {   
      displayData = async ()=>{  
        try{  
          OccupancyType = await AsyncStorage.getItem('selectedOccupType');
        }  
        catch(error){  
          alert(error)  
        }  
      } 
  render(){
    this.displayData();
return(){
```

and code where i am storing is

```
AsyncStorage.setItem('selectedOccupType',selectedOccupType.toString());
```

for example i am storing on screen 1 and i need this in screen 3 and when i go to screen 3 it fetch nothing when i comback to screen 2 and then go forward to screen 3 it work. please help. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call `this.displayData()` in `componentDidMount` and `setState({OccupancyType: OccupancyType})` in `displayData` function.

```
 componentDidMount(){
    this.displayData();
    }
     displayData = async ()=>{  
        try{  
          OccupancyType = await 
      AsyncStorage.getItem('selectedOccupType');
      this.setState({OccupancyType:OccupancyType});
        }  
        catch(error){  
          alert(error)  
        }  
      }
```

then use `this.state.OccupancyType`